# how do i use this curl in excel vba to authenticate and receive session key

Tags: excel, vba, rest, api, http

this curl is used to recieve session key from api

```
    curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{
  "UserId": "ID",
  "Password": "PW"
}' 'https://website.com/api/v1/Login'
```

i need to have the session key generated in excel to use with other codes i wrote. this is what i have so far.

```
    Sub GenAPISKey()

  Dim webServiceURL As String
  Dim actionType As String
  Dim targetWord As String
  Dim actionType2 As String
  Dim targetWord2 As String
  Dim UserID As String
  Dim Password As String

  webServiceURL = "https://website.com/api/v1/Login"
  actionType = "Accept"
  targetWord = "application/json"
  actionType2 = "Content-Type"
  targetWord2 = "application/json"
  UserID = "ID"
  Password = "PW"


  With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "POST", webServiceURL, False
    .SetRequestHeader actionType, targetWord
    .SetRequestHeader actionType2, targetWord2
    .SetCredentials "UserID", "Password", 0

    .Send
    If .Status = 200 Then
      Debug.Print .responseText

    Else
      MsgBox .Status & ": " & .StatusText
    End If
  End With

End Sub
```

Any ideas on what i can try?the Curl works perfect its the vba version of it i can't get to work with the api.

Comment: what response do you get with your current code?

Comment: i get run time error 438 object doesnt support this property or method

Comment: Is that a runtime error from the vba?

Comment: yes when i run it in the excel vba editor the result is always run time error 438"object doesnt support this property or method

Comment: i dont know if this helps but i think it might either be that something is wrong with the way i did ".setcredentials" or  that ".responsetext" isnt what i  need to receive the session key. is it possible that i should have set the password as something other than a string?

Comment: Which line of code generates the error?

Comment: ".set credentials" generates the error. another guess from me is that since in the curl its preceded by -d i need to use something other than ".set credentials" even though its my username and password

Comment: I think you should try to pass username/password in as parameters to the .Open method.

Comment: thank you. now its giving me an access denied runtime error -2147024891. but again it works in curl. i'll post my new code because i must just mot be putting it in right.

Comment: I was able to get a response using the WinHttpRequest object (in my answer). It’s a 404, but I assume that’s because you aren’t using the real url in your example. But, it’s at least not a vba error. Let me know if that works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `.SetCredentials` isn't a member of the `XMLHTTP` object you are using. I have two suggestions.

1) use a different object like the `WinHttpRequest` object:

```
With CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    .Open "POST", webServiceURL, False
    .SetRequestHeader actionType, targetWord
    .SetRequestHeader actionType2, targetWord2
    .SetCredentials "UserID", "Password", 0
    .Send
    If .Status = 200 Then
      Debug.Print .responseText

    Else
      MsgBox .Status & ": " & .StatusText
    End If
  End With
```

2) If you must use the `XMLHTTP` object, try setting the credentials in the `.Open` method call and get rid of the `.SetCredentials` line.

```
With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "POST", webServiceURL, False, "UserID", "Password"
    .SetRequestHeader actionType, targetWord
    .SetRequestHeader actionType2, targetWord2

    .Send
    If .Status = 200 Then
      Debug.Print .responseText

    Else
      MsgBox .Status & ": " & .StatusText
    End If
  End With
```

Edit:

Seams like option one is the way to go for you. Now, I believe you just need to send through the body of JSON that your API wants. In fact, you probably don't even need to set credentials if this is how the API is working. Looking at your `-curl` command, you should try....:

```
With CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    .Open "POST", webServiceURL, False
    .SetRequestHeader actionType, targetWord
    .SetRequestHeader actionType2, targetWord2

    .Send "{""UserId"": ""ID"", ""Password"": ""PW""}"
    If .Status = 200 Then
      Debug.Print .responseText

    Else
      MsgBox .Status & ": " & .StatusText
    End If
  End With
```

Comment: thank you i option 1 has done it for me (im extatic to have finally made progress after trying for so long) but the website is sending back an error response code. the website code says "method not found"... any idea what that could be?

Comment: Since this is a POST request, are you supposed to be sending some sort of JSON body? If so, this JSON string would be passed as a parameter in the `.Send` call. I'm guessing your api doesn't know what to do with whatever you sent it.

Comment: @YerryBalenzuela - actually, looking at the curl command, it looks like your API is expecting a JSON object with username and password as the body of the post? You might try sending the JSON in as mentioned in my above comment with the `.Send` call.

Comment: @YerryBalenzuela - I've added to my answer. See if this helps.

Comment: @YerryBalenzuela make sure you have the double quotes properly escaped for vba strings. (see my edit)

Comment: I do not have words to say how greatful i am ... this was the hardest thing i've ever had to figure out in my life and you are a life saver. it works perfectly.

Comment: @YerryBalenzuela Wonderful! Happy to help! Please consider marking my answer as the accepted answer :-)

Comment: hey i'm trying to repurpose this code to do a "PUT" request but it keeps giving me a "bad request" error. i could really use your help. heres the link to the full question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61398315/need-help-getting-curl-api-request-code-using-excel-vba-to-work-properly

Comment: @YerryBalenzuela - gave it my best shot. hope it helps

Comment: Hey Thank you soo much... with your advice i was able to make it work... the json was a bit picky like you said and what i got to work in curl did need a little editing .